# Tcl regexp variable not matching, how to fix?

Tags: regex, tcl

Unable to get variable working in regexp

Dear Experts,

I'm trying to use a variable in regexp in tcl but could not get it working. Here in the input data and regexp pattern, I am trying to use

```
set line_pattern ac_E13Q_DFLP_B_eqCcell_10_022
set cell_pattern ac_E13Q_DFLP_B_eqCcell

regexp {^"${cell_pattern}".+} $line_pattern match
```

Could someone please help me to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Braces in Tcl are like single quotes in the shell: variables are not substituted within.

```
regexp "^$cell_pattern.+" $line_pattern match
```

---

Your pattern is not a regular expression. You might just want to check if the string **starts with** the prefix.

```
if {[string first $cell_pattern $line_pattern] == 0} {
    puts "starts with!"
}
# or
if {[string match "${cell_pattern}*" $line_pattern]} {
    puts "starts with!"
}
```

Docs:

- [`string first`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M8)
- [`string match`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35)
- the grouping sections of [the Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks, Glenn! I plan to select a specific pattern from the cell_pattern, so I used regexp. Is there a possibility of using regexp somehow?

Comment: I don't understand. Please use an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a literal value in braces in Tcl, you disable *all* substitutions in it. That means that the RE you are looking for is *literally* just `^"${cell_pattern}".+`, and that doesn't match anything (because the end-of-string match `$` can't have anything after it and be satisfied).

I'm going to guess that you want a variable substitution in there. The easiest way, especially as the RE doesn't contain backslashes or square brackets (other Tcl metasyntax), is to just put the whole string in double quotes, like this:

```
regexp "^${cell_pattern}.+" $line_pattern match
```

Or maybe:

```
regexp "^${cell_pattern}(.+)" $line_pattern -> match 
# Just captures the suffix
```

Of course, at that point you have to be careful that the substituted string is a proper RE fragment. This is true in your example.

In more complex cases, it can be useful to use `string map` and/or `format` to build the RE. But I tend to think that if you are getting that complex then you have too complicated an RE.

---

The *specific* matching you're doing here can be also done with `string first`, `string range` and `string length`, but only slightly more complex things get very annoying to do that way. Much more complex things might justify using a parser generator.

Comment: "too complicated an RE" -- that's when I use `-extended` and put some comments in the regex.